# insert / delete post requests in same template django

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, django

I have a table showing data and I have a form with a submit button that inserts data in a mysql db, I added buttons next to each row that say "delete" so I'm able to delete each row from the site too.

I get the id when I click the button but I don't know yet how to pass it to the views, but my main problem now is that the second post isn't working.

*template.py*

```
<tr>
     <td>{{b.ip}}</td>
     <td>{{b.polling_time}}</td>
     <td>{{b.communitydata}}</td>
     <td>{{b.snmp_oid}}</td>
     <td>{{b.lastcheck|date:"Y.m.d H:m:s"}}</td>
     <form action="/services/listpoll/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <td><input type="button" id="{{b.id}}" class="delete_poll" value="Borrar"></td>
     </form>
 </tr>
```

*jquery*

```
$(".delete_poll").click(function(){

          id_poll = $(this).attr('id');

  });
```

*views.py*

```
def listpolls(request):
    connect_mysql = mdb.connect('***', '***', '***', '***')
    cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "select id,ip,polling_time,communitydata,snmp_oid,lastcheck from snmptt_listpolls order by ip desc limit 100"
    cursorMYSQL.execute(query)
    b = cursorMYSQL.fetchall()
    connect_mysql.close()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AddPollForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            ip = form.cleaned_data['poll_ip']
            poll_time = form.cleaned_data['poll_time']
            communitydata = form.cleaned_data['communitydata']
            snmp_oid = form.cleaned_data['snmp_oid']
            lastcheck = form.cleaned_data['lastcheck']

            cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursorMYSQL.execute("""insert into snmptt_listpolls (ip, polling_time, communitydata, snmp_oid) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s')"""%(ip, poll_time, communitydata, snmp_oid))

            connect_mysql.commit()
            connect_mysql.close()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')

        elif request.method == 'POST' and not form.is_valid(): 

            id_poll = '53';

            cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursorMYSQL.execute(""" delete from snmptt_listpolls where id='%s' """%(id_poll))

            connect_mysql.commit()
            connect_mysql.close()

            return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form} ) 

    else:
        form = AddPollForm()
        return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form} )
```

So, this time I'm just trying to check if the post request is working so when I click it will delete the row with the 53 id, but it doesn't work, so I guess I'm doing something wrong and the post is not going through.

Thanks!

Comment: Totally unrelated but why on earth are you doing direct connection to the db using `MySQLdb` instead of using the builtin ORM ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is the second time in two days that I am seeing someone using python mysql library direct, completely bypassing the orm.

Comment: Not only bypassing the orm but also bypassing the dbapi sanitation layer by using string interpolation on user inputs... Little Bobby Table anyone ? And let's not talk about the harcoded connection data and uselessly closing / reopening the connection... I'm surprised the op at least used a django form <g>

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet.So please consider it as a comment.

I don't think the execution will ever reach to the second post

```
elif request.method=="POST":
```

Also why don't you use Django models instead of doing it explicitly with MySQL.

For deleting an item you can use jquery ajax post request with the id of the item and handle it in the view.

Comment: The problem is when posting again I don't know how to differentiate them.

Comment: So you are asking how will you differentiate when you make another post request?

Comment: I have a submit form button that will post data to mysql (insert) and then delete buttons to delete also from the db.

Comment: I haven't used this but it should work:  You can let another view handle this over ajax. For example you can create a new view delete_poll, and you can handle the deletion over ajax and return response via json.

Answer (score 0):

Handling two (or more) different forms in a single view is no rocket science: you just need to identify which form was posted, which is easily done with a hidden input in each form.

```
 <td>
   <!-- HTML doesn't allow <form> around the <td> -->
   <form action="/services/listpoll/" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete">
     <input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="{{b.id}}">
     <input type="button" class="delete_poll" value="Borrar">
   </form>
 </td>
```

Now you can get rid of your useless jquery stuff and handle the deletion in the view:

def listpolls(request):
    # snip MySQLdb code that has nothing to do here,
    # please use the orm or at least the db backend connection

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.post.get("action", "") == "delete":            
        # don't assume - check
        poll_id = request.post.get("poll_id", None)
        if poll_id is not None:
            delete_poll_here()
    else: 
        form = AddPollForm(request.POST)
        # etc
```

Now please do yourself (and whoever will have to maintain you code) a service: learn to properly use Django's ORM, and *also* learn to properly use Python's dbapi... This:

```
cursorMYSQL.execute(
   """insert into snmptt_listpolls 
       (ip, polling_time, communitydata, snmp_oid) 
      values ('%s','%s','%s','%s')
   """ % (ip, poll_time, communitydata, snmp_oid))
```

is wide open to SQL injection. The correct way is

```
cursorMYSQL.execute(
   """insert into snmptt_listpolls 
       (ip, polling_time, communitydata, snmp_oid) 
      values (%s,%s,%s,%s)
   """, (ip, poll_time, communitydata, snmp_oid))
```

but you really don't need this in Django when you have Models and ModelForms.

Comment: I can't use the second example, I get a ProgrammingError.

Comment: I fixed it - no need for the quotes around the placholders

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works with one of my queries, but I get TypeError with another one. I guess it is because of the data type in the mysql table, right?

Comment: @BobbyChenyChen sorry but when it comes to debugging I don't "guess" anything - I read the traceback, inspect my code, variables etc. Now if you used Django properly (in this case using proper Models and ModelForms) you wouldn't waste time debugging mundane details.

Comment: Also, I still can't make the different POSTs work, I'm opening a new question for this as this is getting many comments and too long.